# Conditional statement to break string into two lines, based on spaces and length

Tags: javascript, string, function, conditional-statements

I have a function that breaks a string into two lines. It breaks the string based on where the blank spaces are:

```
 splitSentenceInHalfCC(sentence: string): [string, string] {
    let middle = Math.floor(sentence.length / 2);
    let before = sentence.lastIndexOf(' ', middle);
    let after = sentence.indexOf(' ', middle + 1);


    if (middle - before < after - middle || after === -1) {
      middle = before;
    } else {
      middle = after;
    }

    let s1 = sentence.substr(0, middle);
    let s2 = sentence.substr(middle + 1);

    return [s1, s2];
  }
```

What I want to do now is add an if statement, where IF there are zero spaces, it will break the string into two lines after the first 15 characters, lets say. How can I achieve this? I am quite new to this so not sure how to proceed. Thank you.

```
Example #1 input: This is a Store name and it is detailed.
Example #1 output: This is a Store name 
                   and it is detailed.
Example #2 input: Thisisjustalongstorenamewithnospaces.
Example #2 output: Thisisjustalongstorename
                   withnospaces.
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have just updated my questions with examples at the bottom of inputs and outputs I would like to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, it's pretty clear now, though the whole string `Thisisjustalongstorenamewithnospaces.` is 36 characters long, so if you want to split after the first 35, wouldn't it result in `["Thisisjustalongstorenamewithnospaces",
  "."]`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance that was just an example. For the sake of this, lets say we split it after 15 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is, at the very start of the function, check to see if the sentence `.includes` a space - if not, then return an array with two items, the sentence `slice`d from 0 to 35, and then from 35 onward. (Of course, if you want to change the number of characters, just change the `35` parameter provided to `.slice`)

```js
function splitSentenceInHalfCC(sentence) {
  if (!sentence.includes(' ')) {
    return [
      sentence.slice(0, 35),
      sentence.slice(35),
    ]
  }

  let middle = Math.floor(sentence.length / 2);
  let before = sentence.lastIndexOf(' ', middle);
  let after = sentence.indexOf(' ', middle + 1);


  if (middle - before < after - middle || after === -1) {
    middle = before;
  } else {
    middle = after;
  }

  let s1 = sentence.substr(0, middle);
  let s2 = sentence.substr(middle + 1);

  return [s1, s2];
}
console.log(splitSentenceInHalfCC('This is a Store name and it is detailed.'));
console.log(splitSentenceInHalfCC('Thisisjustalongstorenamewithnospaces.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the string has spaces or not.

```
 splitSentenceInHalfCC(sentence: string): [string, string] {
    let middle = Math.floor(sentence.length / 2);
    let before = sentence.lastIndexOf(' ', middle);
    let after = sentence.indexOf(' ', middle + 1);


    if (middle - before < after - middle || after === -1) {
      middle = before;
    } else {
      middle = after;
    }

    if( before === -1 && after === -1 ){
       middle = 35;
    }

    let s1 = sentence.substr(0, middle);
    let s2 = sentence.substr(middle + 1);

    return [s1, s2];
  }
```

Note: You might want to base the number `35` on the string length.